# Finding open subset of a subspace of the space of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $E := \{ f \in C[-2,2] : |f(0) + f(1)| \le 3 \}$ be a subspace of $C[-2,2]$ with the supremum norm. Is the space $E$ closed and does it contain any open subset of $C[-2,2]$?

Will closedness come from the result that uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence in this case? Because if $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in E$ is a convergent sequence and the limit is $f$, then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ one has that $|f_n(0) + f_n(1)| \le 3$ and now because $f_n \to f$ pointwise one has that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in [-2,2]$ so $$f_n(0) + f_n(1) \to f(0) + f(1).$$

Therefore one has that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge n_0$ implies that $$|f_n(0)+f_n(1) -(f(0)+f(1)|< \varepsilon$$

but from here $$-\varepsilon -(f_n(0)+f_n(1)) < -(f(0)+f(1))<\varepsilon-(f_n(0)+f_n(1))$$

multiplying by $-1$ results in $$\varepsilon+f_n(0)+f_n(1)>f(0)+f(1)>-\varepsilon+f_n(0)+f_n(1).$$

And now taking absolute values $$|\varepsilon| + 3 \ge |\varepsilon|+|f_n(0)+f_n(1)| > |f(0)+f(1)|$$

but when $\varepsilon \to 0$ we get the desired inequality that is $|f(0) + f(1)| \le 3$.

What can we do for this possible open subset here that is being asked also?

Comment: Indeed the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions (i.e., limit wrt to sup norm) is again a continuous function. So if $f_n\in E$ for all $n$ and $f_n\to f$, then $f$ is continuous. So closedness simply requires to check that the $\leq 3$ inequality holds for $f$ too, which should be immediate. Now with the second part, consider the unit ball wrt to the sup norm, i.e. $\{f\in C[-2,2]: \|f\|_\infty<1\}$.

Comment: Comment: $E$ is not a subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi\colon&C[-2,2]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&f(0)+f(1)\end{array}$$is continuous and $E=\varphi^{-1}\bigl([-3,3]\bigr)$; therefore, $E$ is a closed set. Furthermore, $E\supset\varphi^{-1}\bigl((-3,3)\bigr)$, which is an open non-empty set. Of course, $\emptyset$ is also an open subset of $E$.

Comment: Nice one! I completely forgot that we could construct a map from the given space to the reals and use that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.